# Usuários com baixa reputação deveriam poder propor um comentário?

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

Como vocês sabem, é necessário ter [50 pontos de reputação para poder comentar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) em uma publicação não criada por você mesmo. Isso serve para evitar "obrigados", etc.

Acontece que, com muita frequência usuários novatos publicam um "comentário" na forma de resposta (por exemplo, pedindo informações adicionais ao AP), já que esse é o único recurso que ele tem para isso. E então o moderador vai lá e converte a resposta em comentário.

Não seria interessante se ele pudesse propor um comentário? Funcionaria como a proposta de uma edição, ou seja, o comentário teria que ser aprovado por alguém com reputação suficiente. Assim, seria possível evitar que um comentário irrelevante como um simples "obrigado" fosse criado.

Comment: Apenas para constar, há uma explicação oficial [nesta pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/817/12)

Answer (score 6):

[Esta resposta](/q/817) aprofunda mais sobre os motivos por trás da restrição e como a equipe da SE vai tratá-la no futuro.
Por agora, basta saber que não vemos motivos para alterar a regra.

Uma fila de análise de comentários provavelmente seria muito mais movimentada do que qualquer um dos sites teria condições de manter. O SOpt mantém suas filas de análise absolutamente vazias, e parabéns para nós, mas a relação de comentários/post é bem alta, **mesmo** com as restrições de reputação. De uma hora para outra o volume de tempo necessário para manter nossas filas de análise - e dos outros sites da SE - aumentaria bastante, provavelmente se tornando insustentável. Não é isso que queremos.

A questão dos comentários é uma daquelas em que lidar com as *consequências* da regra requer menos tempo e esforço, de todos, do que manter a regra em si.

Answer (score 2):

No nosso site isso seria interessante sim, especialmente enquanto ainda é novo e pequeno.

Em sites de maior movimento, como o Stack Overvflow (e o nosso no futuro, espero), acho que não vale a pena. Como comentários são secundários, uma fila de análise só para eles seria um desperdício de esforço (melhor os analistas focarem nas outras filas).